# Free Allocated Memory Generates Exception - C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, exception, malloc, free

There is a function in my application in which memory is allocated for formatting a port name.  `CreateFile` is called to open the port.  At the end of the function `free` is called to attempt to free the allocated memory.

```
DWORD CSerialPort::Open( wchar_t * port )
{
    DCB dcb = {0};
    LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE pThreadStart;
    void * pvThreadData = NULL;
    wchar_t * pwcPortName = NULL;
    DWORD dwRetVal = ERROR_SUCCESS;

    /* Validate parameters. */

    pwcPortName = (wchar_t *)malloc( wcslen( port ) + 6 );

    if ( pwcPortName == NULL )
    {
        TRACE(_T("CSerialPort::Open : Failed to allocate memory for formatted serial port name.\r\n\tError: %d\r\n\tFile: %s\r\n\tLine: %d\r\n"), ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY, __WFILE__, __LINE__);
        return ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY;
    }

    memcpy( pwcPortName, L"\\\\.\\", 4 * 2 );
    memcpy( pwcPortName + 4, port, wcslen( port ) * 2 + 2 );

    // Get a handle to the serial port.
    _hSerialPort = CreateFile(
        pwcPortName,                    // Formatted serial port
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,   // Access: Read and write
        0,                              // Share: No sharing
        NULL,                           // Security: None
        OPEN_EXISTING,                  // OM port already exists
        FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,           // Asynchronous I/O
        NULL                            // No template file for COM port
        );

    if ( _hSerialPort == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
    {
        TRACE(_T("CSerialPort::Open : Failed to get the handle to the serial port.\r\n\tError: %d\r\n\tFile: %s\r\n\tLine: %d\r\n"), ::GetLastError(), __WFILE__, __LINE__);
        return ::GetLastError();
    }

    /* Initialize the DCB structure with COM port parameters with BuildCommDCB. */

    /* Set the serial port communications events mask with SetCommMask. */

    /* Set serial port parameters with SetCommState. */

    /* Set the serial port communications timeouts with SetCommTimeouts. */

    /* Create thread to handle received data with CreateThread. */

    free( pwcPortName );                 // <-- Exception thrown here.

    return dwRetVal;
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: You make to many assumptions on size. Make these explicit by using sizeof(wchar_t) appropriately. Also dynamically allocating memory is not exception safe look up RAII (aka std::vector/std::wstring in this case).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`malloc` allocates bytes, but you are using the allocated memory to store `wchar_t`.

You have to change the `malloc` size parameter to match your existing `memcpy` usage:

```
pwcPortName = (wchar_t *)malloc( wcslen( port ) + 6 );
```

should be

```
pwcPortName = (wchar_t *)malloc( (wcslen( port ) + 6) * sizeof(wchar_t));
```

Comment: I would use std::wstring to hold a string!

Comment: @Martin - yes, RAII is preferable. If OP redirects answer acceptance, I would not complain.

Answer (score 4):

Easier solution:

```
DWORD CSerialPort::Open( std::wstring const& port )
{
    // ...
    std::wstring portname = L"\\\\.\\" + port;

    // Get a handle to the serial port.
    _hSerialPort = CreateFile(
        portname.c_str(), // ...
```

Don't worry about freeing memory; C++ will now take care of that.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
pwcPortName = (wchar_t *)malloc( sizeof(wchar_t) * (wcslen( port ) + 6) );
```

...because a `wchar_t` is two bytes in a unicode app. You'll have to make a similar change in your second `memcpy` call too.

But this being **C++**, you should use `new` and `delete` instead:

```
pwcPortName = new wchar_t[wcslen( port ) + 6];

//...

delete[] pwcPortName;
```

Comment: `wchar_t` is not 2 bytes. It's at least two bytes, and is two bytes on windows platforms, but isn't everywhere (for example, on POSIX boxes it's usually 4 bytes) Oh, and if it's C++ he shouldn't be using `new` and `delete`; he should be using `vector` ;)

Comment: Considering it's an argument for `CreateFileW`, I believe it's safe to assume this is Windows not POSIX. It really doesn't make sense to write portable non-portable code.

Comment: @MSalters: I find it good discipline to always write code in portable way. Even if the current target is a specific platform. Good practice is a habit that should be re-enforced and who says that the windows platform will not evolve. Assuming 2 bytes is not a good idea it increases your confidence in this (and other code written by the same developer) in the ability to re-use this code without modification in the next version of windows of they adhere to good practice (not platform specific practice).

Comment: @Martin York: If you'd want to target future Windows versions with 4 byte chars, you'd use `TCHAR` and `_T()` and just flip the switch when they add a 4 byte typedef for `TCHAR`. Windows portability is sublty different from C++ portability, and both are sensible in their own right.

Answer (score 1):

This would be neater:

```
DWORD CSerialPort::Open( wchar_t * port )
{
    DCB dcb = {0};
    LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE  pThreadStart;
    void*     pvThreadData = NULL;
    DWORD     dwRetVal     = ERROR_SUCCESS;

    /* Validate parameters. */
    std::wstring  pwcPortName;

    pwcPortName.append(L"\\\\.\\");
    // memcpy( pwcPortName, L"\\\\.\\", 4 * 2 );
    //                                     ^^^ Whats this magic number? sizeof(wchar_t)
    //                                 ^^^ Is this one the size of the string?
    //                                     If you change the string you also need to
    //                                     modify the 4? Thats not good (hard to
    //                                     maintain (or should I say easy to break))
    pwcPortName.append(port);
    // memcpy( pwcPortName + 4, port, wcslen( port ) * 2 + 2 );
    //                      ^^^ Magic Number. Are you sure this is even correct?
    //                          Adding 4 to this moves the pointer 4 * sizeof(wchar_t)
    //                          So now you have an implied dependency on the above code
    //                          in this line. So if the string was changed you would need
    //                          to modify the 4 in two places!
    //                                               ^^^^^^^ * 2 + 2
    //                          Assume the * 2 is (* sizeof(wchar_t))
    //                          And the + 2 is (+ sizeof(wchar_t)) is to make sure
    //                          you copied the null terminator.                  

    // Get a handle to the serial port.
    _hSerialPort = CreateFile(
        pwcPortName.c_str(),            // Formatted serial port
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,   // Access: Read and write
        0,                              // Share: No sharing
        NULL,                           // Security: None
        OPEN_EXISTING,                  // OM port already exists
        FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,           // Asynchronous I/O
        NULL                            // No template file for COM port
        );


    // STUFF


    // No need to free the pointer as we used a std::Wstring to contain it
    // Thus it provides an exception safe memory leak free way of making sure
    // the memory is freeed.

    return dwRetVal;
}
```

Comment: @Jim Fell: It may be the length of a wchar_t character on your current system with the compiler you are using. But that just makes me not want to use your code. Who says that this will hold true in the next version of WIndows?